# iOS push notifications received while in app but not on home screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am experiencing a weird issue on an iOS app that I have never seen before.

Push notifications are coming through when the user is in the application.  I have logic that draws a custom view when the proper method is triggered in the AppDelegate upon receiving the push notification.

However, if the user backs out of the app to the home screen, iOS is not showing any push notifications for the app anymore.  My understanding is that this part is handled at the OS level.  It should automatically set the badge number and show a pop-up which the user can engage to jump into the app from the push notification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was sending the push incorrectly from the server. I was using Parse and omitted the `alert` key on my JSON payload. This is a cURL script that ended up working for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MY_APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MY_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "where": {
    "userguid": "some-user-id-goes-here"
  },
  "data": {
    "alert": "OH HI THERE",
    "badge": "0",
    "content-available": "1",
    "notificationtype": "SOME_ARBITRARY_KEY"
  }
}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple change the way push notifications request permissions in iOS 8.

Seems like you are partially there as you receive the push when your app is open but this bit is extracted from the iOS SDK documentation.

If you want your app’s push notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must call the `registerUserNotificationSettings:` method to request the types of notifications you want to use. If you do not call that method, the system delivers all push notifications to your app silently. Because the registration process takes into account the user’s preferred notification settings, requesting access to user-facing notification types also does not guarantee that they will be granted. To find out what notification settings are available, use the `currentUserNotificationSettings` method.

So looks like your notifications don't have the permission to be shown to the user and are silently send to the app.

In any case if you can paste your code would be helpful for a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of push notification. If the field alert is empty, the push notification will not display a banner. When you're inside the app it will trigger the "didReceivePushNotification". Maybe the problem is alert field is empty. Im using this tool that simulates push. https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }    
}
```